# Error: iTunes Store Operation Failed description length:3574725

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appicon

I'm trying to upload app to Appstore but getting couple of errors, one related to icon transparency and other seems due to the same issue. I tried multiple version of png, jpeg after removing alpha channel but no success. Any clue why this error message is coming?

I could upload the image to ituneconnect App icon and it works there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to always accompany another error. I got rid of this by fixing the other error reported along with this. It worked for me, hopefully it works for you. In your case, you may want to remove the alpha channel in your appstore ion. You can do this by opening the icon in preview and unchecking the alpha box at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

Although first error points this is "description length" issue, I was able to solve this by just removing the alpha channel of ios marketing icon, the big 1024x1024px image. There are probably other tools that can do this but I used [ImageMagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) from the command line, like this:

```
convert input.png -alpha off output.png
```

After removing alpha channel from marketing icon image, I was able to upload the app with no problems.